# How to do something on every first letter?

Tags: javascript

```
var s='Color sentence';
```

My task is to do something on every first consonant . For example in this sencente "Color sentence" i need to color letters C,L,R,S,N,E,C etc.

But i need code to count every first letter .Help(I'm newbie.) ?

Comment: Strings don't have colors ?

Comment: "*For example C,L,R,S*" Where do the `L,R,S` come from? Are you trying to affect consonants or all characters at odd/even positions in the string? "*First*" suggests the `C` alone for leading the string.

Comment: Do you have some HTML to go with that?

Comment: `C`,`L`,`R`,`S` is the sequence of consonants in that sentence (albeit capitalised). The question is a little unclear, when you say 'on every first letter' do you mean on every consonant? You should review and edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Do you mean every other letter? I.e. C, l, r, s, n, e and c in your example string.

Comment: @user3054753 please [read this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first)

Comment: Yeah Guffa,thats right ...

Comment: Tnx @IngoBürk i think you solved my problem.

Comment: Try to do your homework yourself then ask only the part you are stuck at.

Comment: I am trying,i spend 2 hours on this and i couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're going to insert that string as HTML ?

```
var s = 'Color sentence';
var a = s.split(' ');

for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = '<span style="color:red">' + a[i].charAt(0) + '</span>' + a[i].slice(1);
}

var s = a.join(' ');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5uftV/)

for every other letter in the string, you'd do:

```
var s = 'Color sentence';
var a = s.split('');

for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if (i%2)
        a[i] = '<span style="color:red">' + a[i].charAt(0) + '</span>' + a[i].slice(1);
}

var s = a.join('');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5uftV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
s[0] //to get the first character in the string.
var x = "Hello";
var y = x[0];
alert(y);
```

Output: "H"

Comment: Yeah but i need to do that on every first letter...Hmm,dont know how to explain it ... For example i need to color letters 1,3,5,7,9 etc .

Comment: Loop through the strings you need to change?

Answer (score 0):

To do somewthing with every other character, you can use a regular expression to put an HTML element around them so that you can style them:

```
s = s.replace(/(^|.)(.)/g, '$1<span>$2</span>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/vLEhh/

---

Regular expression explanation:

```
(^|.) - catches the beginning of the string or one character into $1
(.)   - catches one character into $2
```

So, the expression matches either the start of the string or one character, followed by another character. The first match in the string will be the first character, from then on it will match two characters at a time.

Comment: This is good,but I need to do this code only in JS,without html and css.

Comment: @dexMorgan: Then what do you mean by "to color letter"? A character in a string can't have a color.